# String does not show html tags prior to output

Tags: richhtmlfield

I am taking a value from a string from a text column

```
String str = myListItem[field name].toString()
```

In many cases the field may contain html which I wish to remove but it is somehow not visibly contained in `str`. When `str` is output to the webpart it still has the html tags.

How can I return the field value with the html tags in the text?

Comment: Sean, you mean the text contains HTML and you want to treat is as a string and show up on Label ?

Answer (score 0):

use `Server.HtmlDecode(string)` `Server.HtmlEncode(string)` to encode and decode HTML.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE! While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer] for general guidelines.